# How can I create an action that hides or shows layers by a specific name in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, actions

I have some layers in a PSD that are named "@bounds". I'd like to create an action that will either show or hide any layers in the doc that match that layer name. Is this something that can be done through Actions?

Comment: Is there more than one "@bounds" layer per file?

Comment: @cockypup yes, there are several.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can be done with actions, and I'm not aware of a plug-in that would do what you want, but you should be able accomplish that with scripting. It would help if you knew some javascript.

You can find more information here:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html

Comment: `activeDocument.artLayers[i].visible = true;` you can reference by `("name")` or index `(1)`. For the OP's use, one needs to iterate through the whole list (`for (i=0;i < docRef.artLayers.length ;i++)`) and search for the string inside the layer `.name`

Comment: @horatio That's worth expanding a little and making it an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using CS6 (cloud version) or CC, the Layers panel allows you to filter the visibility of layers by name.

At the moment, filtering isn't something you can record in an action, although it's probably been added to what's scriptable (I've not checked). It does, however, make selective hide/unhide very quick and easy.

[image]

Change the filter from `Kind` to `Name` and type in the text you want to filter for.

[image]

From there, it's a quick swipe of the mouse down the eyeballs to hide or unhide all those layers.

The red button toggles the filter off and on, so you can go back and forth very quickly. The text is also sticky, allowing you to use other filters for different purposes, and switch back to "Text" with your entry intact.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. You have to name your layer first then be sure that this layer is not selected when you start recording your action. After that you only have to hide it and the action will record . Then just stop recording. If you want to make an action to unhide it you have to do another action layer and record with the same process but just instead of hiding the layer you unhide it. 
In my presets I've done that, I have two fonctions, F2 hide the "Rough" layer and F3 unhide the "Rough" layer. 
I hope I've been clear.